# How to remedy TLS handshake issue while forwarding packets between two NATs?

Tags: ssl, iptables, firewall, routing, nat

There is a local network with Wifi router working as NAT server, which is connected to an ISP. It's needed to place a firewall between the router and ISP which filters incoming and outcoming traffic, because the router's built-in firewall is too simplistic.

So a machine with two NICs (the intended firewall), running Debian Stretch was added between the router and ISP:

```
[Wifi router(NAT server)]- - - - -[eth1]=[firewall(NAT server)]=[ppp0]
     |                                                            |
     |                                                            |
     |                                                            |
[local network]                                                 [ISP]
```

Currently, the firewall is tested only on forwarding packets between ISP and the router, so only three forwarding iptables rules were added to it:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o ppp0 -j ACCEP
```

These rules apparently are not sufficient for performing a flawless forwarding because some https addresses cannot be opened anymore in browsers in the local network and freeze with the "Perfoming TLS handshaking..." line in the status bar.

Notably, almost all major websites such as gmail, youtube, bing, reddit etc. doesn't have this problem. So the cause of this problem lies maybe in different TLS protocol versions, or different certificate classes or different configuration etc.

Interfaces on firewall machine are configured as follows:

```
$ ip link
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC_ADDRESSS>
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC_ADDRESS>
4: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1460 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 3
    link/ppp 

$ ip addr
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC_ADDRESS>
    inet 10.*.*.*/21 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ***/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC_ADDRESS>
    inet 192.168.2.1/24 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ***/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1460 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 3
    link/ppp 
    inet 10.*.*.* peer 81.*.*.*/32 scope global ppp0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

How can this problem be remedied?

Comment: How did you configure the network interfaces of the Debian machine? What about the wireless router? Did you remember to disable NAT on it, put it in AP mode, etc?

Comment: @Michael for interfaces configuration please see the updated question. As for disabling NAT on the router, the question is namely about preserving two NATs. And two NATs work OK with the majority of sites including stackexchange for example. But e.g. github.com - doesn't.

Comment: You forgot the wireless router configuration? And you seem to have removed a bunch of information from the interface configuration, with no obvious pattern. There's nothing there that needs to be obfuscated anyway; don't waste your time.